# Build failing with "Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0)" message

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 4.5.4 along with Java plugin 3.5. For a few days I get the following exception on a single project (out of 60+ project, 2 mio NCLOC) but can't find a way to fix it:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project main: Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project main: Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line must be null or greater than zero (got 0)
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:88)
    at org.sonar.api.issue.internal.DefaultIssue.setLine(DefaultIssue.java:197)
    at org.sonar.core.issue.DefaultIssueBuilder.build(DefaultIssueBuilder.java:123)
    at org.sonar.core.issue.DefaultIssueBuilder.build(DefaultIssueBuilder.java:35)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.bridges.ChecksBridge.reportIssues(ChecksBridge.java:74)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.Bridges.reportIssues(Bridges.java:93)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.Bridges.save(Bridges.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:87)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.executeOldVersion(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.executeOldVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:284)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:99)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube' marked build as failure
```

I ran `mvn` with `-X` and `-e` options, and the last debug log before Maven build failure and thrown exception is the following:

```
[INFO] [16:16:38.710] Java Test Files AST scan done: 90 ms
[INFO] [16:16:38.710] Package design analysis...
[INFO] [16:16:38.710] 2/2 source files have been analyzed
[DEBUG] [16:16:38.710] 9 packages to analyze
[DEBUG] [16:16:38.710] 0 cycles
[DEBUG] [16:16:38.710] 0 feedback edges
[INFO] [16:16:38.747] Package design analysis done: 37 ms
[DEBUG] [16:16:38.754] Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@482eb3a8[id=34933,key=aaa.bbb:main,qualifier=TRK], with key ccc-aaa.bbb:main
```

Therefor I have no clue which file (if any) is causing this exception. BTW, nothing is written to `sonar.log` on server side.

I had a look at [other posts having a similar exception message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsonarqube%5D%20Line%20must%20be%20null%20or%20greater%20than%20zero%20%28got%200%29), but none match my context (I'm not using SQ 5.2, nor Java plugin 3.7.)

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the possibility to upgrade to the latest version of the Java plugin? Because such issues were reported quite some time on some rules and fixed along the way, so you might be lucky and have this fixed just by updating the plugin.

Comment: Indeed it fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment : please upgrade your version of the sonar-java plugin, this issue has been fixed in sonar-java 3.7.1 (released specifically to fix this issue) see this issue [SONARJAVA-1360](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1360)